# Postgresql with java: query produced no result after insert

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I write a little program to admin my video collection.

```
/*
insert new data set into the table
*/
int next = 0;
rs = st.executeQuery("Select max(category_id) from category;");
if (rs.next()) {
    next = rs.getInt(1) + 1;
    System.out.println(next);
}
String query = "INSERT INTO category VALUES (" + next + ", 'Mystics', now());";
rs = st.executeQuery(query);
//on this place is the exception thrown
// this will not execute anymore
rs = st.executeQuery("DELETE FROM category WHERE name = 'Mystics';");
```

The program can select on tables, make joins but insert make trouble.
I try to insert some new data in my table (see Java-code). After the second test the output show me that the data was inserted. But after Insert was an exception thrown.
1 & 2 are the tests from yesterday and today. (3) was inserted but not selected yet.

```
1   Mystics 2015-07-05
2   Mystics 2015-07-06
3
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: query produced no result.
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:287)
at postgre_java.Zetcode.main(Zetcode.java:55)
```

do you have some advises for me?

Comment: `executeUpdate()` i think

Comment: Use [prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not manipulate data with read statements!
If you want to insert, update, delete data in db use

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
stmt.executeUpdate(SQL);
```

executeQuery returns resultset, but all that INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE can return is number of affected rows and that is what executeUpdate is returning.

And never, never, never*100 use string concatenation in SQL use Prepared statements!

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you use `executeQuery` for a `SELECT` statement or some other statement which returns something. If you want to execute an `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` without returning something, you should use `executeUpdate()`.

Answer (score 0):

[`Statement#executeUpdate()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate%28java.lang.String%29) is meant for that purpose

```
String query = "INSERT INTO category VALUES (" + next + ", 'Mystics', now());";
int noOfRows= st.executeQuery(query)
```

but it doesnt return a `ResultSet` , rather the no of rows affected that you could store into an `Integer`

Also your is highly vulnerable to [Sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) , try using the [`PreparedStatements`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) to safeguard your code